# android application running in debug mode only

Tags: android

Friends, my android application runs in debug mode only even if i click the run button of the eclipse or run it by touching on its icon on the device. what will be reason for this?? anybody has any idea about it??

Answer (score 3):

It is a little late but maybe this may help someone.

What worked for me was to reboot the device through adb like this run `adb reboot`

Rebooting the phone by myself didn't work before that

Answer (score 2):

Is it working if you uninstall your app and click the run button of the eclipse? If yes, probably the reason is that android keep some data in memory even if you close the app, especially it's concerning static members, or references which are not freed by GC. Under debug you get the new instance of your app and it's working as it's when you uninstall/install it. When you click the run button of the eclipse the app might not be installed again and some data will be reused. You should carefuly manage your app data. Firstly read this [article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: uninstalled the application from the device and click the RUN button, fron console i have seen that the insatlling speed of applicatin is vrey fast and it is again in debug mode. i have read that article. i have somany views in my application and that are initiated in onCreate() method. Article said to use getApplicationContext() for long living references. Could you please help me to use that??

Comment: That's like 6 questions, unrelated to your original question, inside a comment to another answer...

Comment: Right, it's a separate and not easy task. For the present you could initialise all your viriables in onCreate or somewhere. Try to find which variable affects your app behavior.

Comment: Friends, I uninstalled the application before each installing. Thus i solved the problem of debugging issue. But even after i close the application the logcat shows that the application is running and gives the data that  i put in a thread other than main thread. when i uninstall application the logcat stops data displaying. From this i concluded that the thread is not stopped. Is this right?? then how can i solve the problem??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it doing as follow:

1. I uninstalled the app from my phone
2. ./adb kill-server
3. ./adb start-server

Now it is working for me. Hope it helps.